# Changes in SharePoint Powershell CAML Query Effect not Taken

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, caml

In my `CAML` query for a SharePoint Power-shell script, the changes made in the `CAML` query is not taken effect.

May I know what am I doing wrong in my code snippet below?

```
cls
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Set config variables
$baseUrl="http://test.com/"
$RDlistName ="RecordsDocument/Forms/TestReport"

#Get Web and List Objects
$web = Get-SPWeb $baseUrl
$RDlist = $web.Lists[$RDlistName]

#Define the CAML Query
$RDquery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$RDquery.Query = "@
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='ContentType' />
        <Value Type='Text'>Folder Content Type</Value> 
        #changes to above filter with an incorrect value still returns result *****
    </Eq>
</Where>"

#Get List Items matching the query
$RDitems = $RDlist.GetItems($RDquery)
$RDcount = 1

Write-host "Total Number of Folders in RecordsDocument:"$RDitems.count
Write-host ""

#Loop through Each Item
ForEach($RDitem in $RDitems)
{
    #Do something
    Write-host $RDcount"." $RDitem["Title"] "|" $RDitem["ContentType"]

    foreach($RDroleAssignment in $RDitem.RoleAssignments)  
    {
        Write-Host - $RDroleAssignment.Member.Name
    }
    $RDcount +=1
}
```

---

EDIT: In addition, the following error was observed..

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>
> D:\User\test.ps1:25 char:1
>
> - $RDitems = $RDlist.GetItems($RDquery)
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>   ```

Comment: using this  $RDlist.GetItems($RDquery) and folder content type filtration use this 

<Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Text'>Folder</Value></Eq>

Comment: Hi @JayneshSharma, I have changed it to `($RDquery)` but the same error appeared. I have amended my post too.

Comment: your list name cant be like this use list title or name like($RDlistName ="RecordsDocument") .not url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test script(hope it helps):

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

#Set config variables
$baseUrl="http://site/"
$RDlistName ="MyDoc"

#Get Web and List Objects
$web = Get-SPWeb $baseUrl
$RDlist = $web.Lists[$RDlistName]

#Define the CAML Query
$RDquery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$RDquery.Query = "@
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='ContentType' />
        <Value Type='Computed'>Folder</Value>        
    </Eq>
</Where>"

#Get List Items matching the query
$RDitems = $RDlist.GetItems($RDquery)
$RDcount = 1

Write-host "Total Number of Folders in RecordsDocument:"$RDitems.count
Write-host ""

#Loop through Each Item
ForEach($RDitem in $RDitems)
{
    #Do something
    Write-host $RDcount"." $RDitem["Title"] "|" $RDitem["ContentType"]

    foreach($RDroleAssignment in $RDitem.RoleAssignments)  
    {
        Write-Host - $RDroleAssignment.Member.Name
    }
    $RDcount +=1
}
```

[image]